# Infinite series : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{(3i-1)}{(4i-3)} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to evaluate this?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{(3i-1)}{(4i-3)} $$

Comment: Do you mean $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{(3i-1)}{(4i-3)}$$

Comment: The sum converges by the Ratio Test. Do you want the value of the sum?

Comment: @RossMillikan, Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sum this in terms of the [hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function). Here is a result by maple

$$ 2\,{ _2F_1\left( 1, \frac{5}{3}; \,\frac{5}{4};\,\frac{3}{4}\right)}. $$

Comment: But of course it is essentially the definition of that hypergeometric.

Comment: @GEdgar: It is the most possible closed form solution.

Answer (score 1):

Nope it doesn't diverge the limit is $2 \cdot \text{Hypergeometric2F1}[1,\frac{5}{3},\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{4}]$  (according to Mathematica)
I Interpret it as 
$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{3i-1}{4i-3}$

Comment: The Value is about 13.2047328961513303884487902215

Answer (score 1):

An answer is
$$
3^{-1/4}2^{7/3}B\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{17}{12},\frac{3}{4}\right) \approx
13.2047328961513303884487902215
$$
where we have used the **incomplete Beta function**
$$
B(\nu,\mu,x) := \int_0^x t^{\nu-1}(1-t)^{\mu-1}\;dt
$$

.....
I took the hypergeometric and looked it up an a table
.....